# How do you add another collectionView on CollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, collectionview

[It covers up the whole collectionViewController everytime I put the collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXV4p.jpg)

[This is what I'm trying to make, another collectionView that I can scroll horizontally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl1My.jpg)
How do you do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can resize it afterwards? Also, you can put it directly as a subview on the target view by dragging it into the left panel instead.

Comment: Use a simple `ViewController`then add both collectionViews, set constraints and implements their delegates

Comment: I dont know how to resize the CollectionViewController, can you shoot me an email? im really stuck here. please thank you @Larme

Comment: @Santiagocarmonagonzalez the collectionViewLayout I use wont appear if I use ViewController